# Redirect user back to flutter app for supabase password reset

Tags: flutter, supabase

I'm fairly new to supabase, flutter, and programming in general. I'm trying to achieve the following:

When the user taps the "Reset Email" link in the password reset email, they are redirected back to my Flutter app, but not to the SetNewPasswordScreen. How can I make sure that the user is redirected to the SetNewPasswordScreen specifically?

In summary, this is the user flow I am trying to achieve:

1. User submits their email address on ForgotPasswordScreen
2. User recieves email
3. User taps "Reset Email" link in email
4. User is redirected to SetNewPasswordScreen

The following call triggers the password reset email to be sent to the user:

```
      final response = await supaClient.auth.resetPasswordForEmail(email,
          redirectTo: kIsWeb
              ? null
              : 'io.supabase.pickleballislife://forgotpassword-callback/');
```

In my ios/Runner/Info.plist file, I've inserted the following block:

```
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>'io.supabase.pickleballislife://forgotpassword-callback/'</string>
        </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

And in my android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file, I've inserted the following block:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST -->
                <data
                android:scheme="io.supabase.pickleballislife"
                android:host="forgotpassword-callback" />
            </intent-filter>
```

The route for the SetNewPasswordScreen is:

```
  static const ROUTE_NAME = '/forgotpassword-callback';
```

and I've defined it in my routes the following way:

```
SetNewPasswordScreen.ROUTE_NAME: (BuildContext context) {
    return SetNewPasswordScreen();
  },
```

And on my ForgotPasswordScreen, I've set up the following AuthChangeEvent listener:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final _authSubscription = supaClient.auth.onAuthStateChange.listen((data) {
      final AuthChangeEvent event = data.event;
      if (event == AuthChangeEvent.passwordRecovery) {
        goToNamed(
          SetNewPasswordScreen.ROUTE_NAME,
          replace: true,
        );
      }
    });
    _authSubscription.cancel();
  }
```

How can I ensure that once the user taps the "Reset Password" link in their email, they are redirected to the SetNewPassword screen and not just my mobile app in general?

Answer (score 2):

Your plist file should contain only `io.supabase.pickleballislife`, because that is your scheme

```xml
<key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>io.supabase.pickleballislife</string>
        </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Then instead of going to `io.supabase.pickleballislife://forgotpassword-callback/`, you can go to `io.supabase.pickleballislife://callback/forgotpassword`. The key is that we are now redirecting to the `/forgotpassword` path. BTW, there is nothing wrong with having `forgotpassword-callback` as the host, but it might be confusing, so I have changed it to `callback`. You may want to update the setting on Android as well.

Now you can setup your routes using [GoRouter](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Configuration-topic.html),

```dart
GoRouter(
  routes: [
    ...
    GoRoute(
      path: '/forgotpassword',
      builder: (context, state) => SetNewPasswordScreen(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

You also need to setup some additional configuration on both iOS and Android side to enable Flutter deep linking. You can find the instruction [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking).

With this, you should be able to call the following and the user will be redirected to the password reset page! Also remember to update the URL configuration on your Supabase dashboard to accept `io.supabase.pickleballislife://callback/forgotpassword/` as additional URL.

```dart
final response = await supaClient.auth.resetPasswordForEmail(email,
          redirectTo: kIsWeb
              ? null
              : 'io.supabase.pickleballislife://callback/forgotpassword/');
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for a very thoughtful answer! May I ask, is the GoRouter implementation necessary or is it sufficient to simply define the ROUTE_NAME in my existing routes configuration?

Comment: @SamYoon
My pleasure. When you say "define the ROUTE_NAME in my existing routes configuration", do you mean to use named routes? It will sort of work, but Flutter officially no longer recommends using named routes. You can read more about it here: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation#limitations

Comment: Yes I've defined ths following on my SetNewPasswordScreen:

  static const ROUTE_NAME = '/forgot_password';

Comment: And in my Routes.dart, I have defined the following:
  SetNewPasswordScreen.ROUTE_NAME: (BuildContext context) {
    return SetNewPasswordScreen();
  },

Comment: However, when the user clicks the Forgot Password link in the recovery email, they are redirected back to whatever screen they were on and not the SetNewPasswordScreen, specifically. Any idea why that might be? A simple named route should be sufficient for this functionality but the reset link is not pushing the named route.

Comment: I found this Supabase article recommending the use of an auth change event listener in Javascript, so I'm now wondering if there is an equivalent in Flutter:

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-resetpasswordforemail

Comment: By chance, is there a public GitHub repo with the implementation you described that you could share? It would be helpful to review the full implementation. 

With the GoRouter implementation, the user is sometimes redirected to the SetNewPasswordScreen and sometimes not. I can’t figure out why.

Comment: @SamYoon Using onAuthStateChanged is not recommended in JS either. That link you provided says if you want to have a callback. onAuthStateChanged is not meant to be used for navigation. About your app not redirecting the user to the correct screen upon clicking the recovery link, make sure you are only relying on deep link to redirect users, and nothing else. Remove all of the onAuthStateChanged or any other navigation logic that might fire upon user entering the app. And lastly, there is no public example at the moment, but we are working on one. Hopefully we will have one soon.

Comment: Noted with thanks. When configuring associated domains is it correct to use the supabase redirect url? In this case:

io.supabase.pickleballislife

Comment: @SamYoon No, actually your deep link can be anything you want it to be. It doesn't have to contain supabase at all!

Comment: @dshukertjr hi I tried what your solution suggested but im also facing the same problem where they are redirected back to whatever screen they were on. I want to redirect to my initial route of "/" and my redirect url after authenticatin is "io.supabase.launchlabnus://login-callback/#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJ...."
it seems that my go router is not matching my initial route with the returned deeplink how should i approach this problem?

Comment: @dshukertjr it seems that go_router doesn't match the fragment with my path do u have an idea how to work around this?

Comment: @jmsandiegoo You are right. I had forgotten one little configuration. In your info.plist file, you should add a key of `FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled` and value of `true`. With this configuration, go_router should automatically take you to the forgotpassword page. I have edited my answer to include the change as well.

Comment: @dshukertjr i tried that as well but my go router wont match the link with the fragment could you help me when you are free here's my SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517577/flutter-supabase-cant-redirect-user-back-to-splash-screen-after-google-auth-w